# AzureAD/Microsoft365: I'd like to change our users UPN from InitalLetterGivenName.Surname@domain.com to GivenName.Surname@domain.com

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft365

I guess it could be done *easily* via Powershell and the AzureAD module however I've got couple of doubts and it seems I can't find the proper documentation to help me to dispel them.

- When I change the UPN in AzureAD will it be automatically changed and propagated to Microsoft 365 services especially Exchange Online? Or should I then change UPN in EXO too?
- When I change the UPN in AzureAD the PrimaryEmailAddress should change too, is there an automation to keep the former address as alias (I mean, SMTP and smtp entries in the proxyaddress field)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXO is using Azure AD as the user directory. This means that changes made for a user in Azure AD will automatically be reflected in EXO (where relevant, of course).

If you want to ensure the previous email address as an alias I suggest you set this in EXO as part of your scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @MMThornberg. Just a quick additional question, since I'm unable to add an alias if the email address is already set so I'd change the UPN and then add the "former" email address as a new alias. I'm going to run it in a single script however do you think there is a possibility that users lose emails?

Comment: Correct, you should add the alias after making the change ;-) regarding the email, you are only changing the naming reference doing this, so as long as you do not remove either the user or the EXO license emails are intact

Comment: Thank you very much @MMThornberg!